# JSoup : How to get an html element, and set the content in a Textview

Tags: java, android, textview, jsoup

Using Jsoup, is it possible to get an html element, and set the content in a Textview and keeping html tag formated ?

Example :

1. I get woth JSoup : `<span color="red">Hello</span>`
2. Set `<span color="red">Hello</span>` in my textview
3. Output is Hello (in red) in my app

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Jsoup Output String Here"));
```

you can follow this example for jsoup

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links